# Google Analytics track custom properties

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

How do I track a custom property for each page on my site? For example, as well as tracking page views, bounce rate, etc for a given page, I want to be able to track a custom property as well (specifically, the number of times someone clicks a specific link on a specific page).

Below is a mockup of what I want to be able to see (either on Google Analytics dashboard or via GAPI):

[image]

Comment: Always wondered if it was possible to do this, I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with event tracking. See google's guide for more information:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Example:

```
<head>
...
<script>
var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXX-X'],['_setDomainName', 'example.com'],['_trackPageview']];
...
</head>
<body>
...
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Custom Clicks Category', 'Custom Link Clicks Action', 'Custom Label', 1]);">Click me</a>
...
<script>
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
</script>
```

The final param, which I didn't use is the `non-interaction` parameter and it's usage depends on your particular case and how you would like bounce rate effected. Read about it at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#non-interaction